# JWT and Azure AD to secure Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, jwt

I have a Spring Boot Rest Api with JWT integration. Currently from Postman, I make a POST request  to authenticate endpoint, including username and password, and obtain an access token.
But can Azure AD be used along with JWT, instead of hardcoded user details ?

Comment: Hi @bee, what do you mean by Azure AD be used along with JWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you obtain token with username and password, that bases on [Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows.

I'm not sure what you mean about Azure AD with JWT.

If you would like to obtain access token **with a signed-in user(not hardcoded user details)**, [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) is better for you. You could also [request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) in Postman.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=xxx
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read
&code=<authorization_code from "/authorize" endpoint>
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

If you would like to obtain access token **without users**, you could use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). In the client credentials flow, permissions are granted directly to the application itself by an administrator, so you must use application permissions.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=xxx
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret=xxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```